# Firebase: No such file or directory GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework/Headers

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I'm trying to add Firebase to my iOS project, but something is going wrong and I don't know what is.

My pod is the next:

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do
 pod 'Firebase'
 pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

And I'm getting this error:

> #### Error
>
> ``` Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory -
>   /../MyProject/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks/GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework/Headers

This only happens when I'm trying to add Firebase to the project. When I tried add only Google Maps it worked.

**UPDATE:**

When I try to add the old version of Firebase it works!

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do
 pod 'GoogleMaps'
 pod 'Firebase', '2.5.1'
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue. It was resolved with the following steps:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
sudo gem update cocoapods
pod install
```